# JavaScript initial variables and persistance

Tags: javascript, variables, persistence, html

I'm sure that this is a rather simple question.  I am making a website with several pages.  Is there a way to declare variables when (and only when) the homepage first loads, and then reference those variables later?  I saw that using localStorage or sessionStorage could be of use, or declaring global variables.  My precise problem is that there is a variable, hasChanged, that is false only when the web page first loads.  When you click a button, it will set hasChanged to true, as well as change various things about the web page.  However, whenever I visit other pages and come back, it has reset to false (whereas I want it to still be true).  And, furthermore, is there a good way to have the other pages access this same variable?

Answer (score 0):

[SessionStorage](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/sessionStorage) is going to be your best bet.

```
if (sessionStorage.getItem('hasChanged') {
    sessionStorage.setItem('hasChanged', 'true');
}
```

and on other pages.

```
var hasChanges = sessionStorage.getItem('hasChanged');
```

If they are truly other pages. If you have a lot of data that neesd to be shared between multiple pages. Consider [Single Page Applications](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Single-page_application)